# React Axios-Hooks: Assign URL and call useAxios with a switch statement?

Tags: reactjs, axios

Trying to create a hook that uses a switch statement to assign various URLs to the useAxios() call with a switch statement. I'm running into a problem I'm hoping for input on:

React won't let me move the call after the switch section, I get a compiler error stating I'm trying to use a hook conditionally it's clearly outside of the Switch statement.

Here's the current test code (with just a state coded URL and with the useAxios call before the switch):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import useAxios from 'axios-hooks';

export const UseTestAPI = (requestAPI, requestData) => {
   var returnData = "";
   var dataURL = "";

   const [testURL, setTestURL] = useState('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
   const [{ data, loading, error }, refetch] = useAxios(testURL);
   console.log("data in Communicator:", data);

   switch (requestAPI)
   {

    case "getTest1Data":
        setTestURL('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2');
        break;    
    case "getSourceData":
        break;

    default:
        return "ERR: API Does Not Exist";

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the default value of a hook like you are trying to. Well there might be a way, it's JS where anything is possible, but that is not a great way to use hooks.

`useAxios` will take a URL like have given it or a [config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config). Also, your `refetch` function will also take a `config` you can pass a partial to both. I would probably not a make a call in the init but rather init with a baseUrl and options set to not request then. Then send a path with a call in a `useEffect` that will get called when the component mounts. Then you can send a partial `config` in your `switch` that will prepend the '2' to the `baseUrl`.

You could also skip the `useEffect` call and just send a `url: '2'` in the init without the options, whichever you prefer.

```js
export const UseTestAPI = (requestAPI, requestData) => {
   var returnData = "";
   var dataURL = "";

   const [{ data, loading, error }, refetch] = useAxios({baseUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'}, {manual:true});
   useEffect(() => {
         refetch({url: '1'});
      }, []
   );

   console.log("data in Communicator:", data);

   switch (requestAPI)
   {


    case "getTest1Data":
        refetch({url: '2'});
        break;    
    case "getSourceData":
        break;

    default:
        return "ERR: API Does Not Exist";

    }
 }
```

Comment: What about multiple base URLs?

Comment: You can change the config as much as you want. Or just overwrite it with a new complete url.

Comment: I guess that's what I'm asking. Do you do that in the refetch, or just append in the refetch? I'd like to be able to change the full URL in those switch cases.

Comment: Also what about when it returns Undefined for the first few times, is there a way to ignore that?

Comment: @user13709264 It sounds like the answer works? Comments aren't a discussion forum, we will probably get flagged with this one. If the answer fixes your issue, you should accept it. If it leads to a new question, it is appropriate to ask a new one. If it doesn't work let us know the error or issue.

Comment: It's actually not working. Refetch in the switch keeps generating a compilation error, coming up as "undefined". Spefically "TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined"